# Партицирование Postgres для update

Tags: postgresql

А партицирование может работать с update? Такое подобие горячего\ холодного хранилища? При переключении флага active\not_active строка попадает либо в одну либо в другую партицию?

Answer (score 0):

Может работать. Нужно создать правила которые будут выполняться при обновлении данных

```
CREATE RULE active_active_notactive AS ON UPDATE TO you_table 
WHERE (you_status='active')DO INSTEAD (INSERT INTO you_table_active VALUES (new.*); DELETE FROM you_table_notactive WHERE id = new.id;
CREATE RULE active_notactive_active AS ON UPDATE TO you_table 
WHERE (you_status='notactive')DO INSTEAD (INSERT INTO you_table_notactive VALUES (new.*); DELETE FROM you_table_active WHERE id = new.id;
```

Документация https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createrule.html